# Parsing FIX messages, stress testing

Tags: stress-testing, fix-protocol

I am doing some stress testing on FIX message parsing on a GPU. What is a reasonable number of messages I should aim to parse per second?

thanks

Comment: You mean the trading protocol FIX, or some other FIX? I see, it's the trading protocol.

Comment: That depends on the FIX library you are using.There isn't any benchmark on FIX as such.

Comment: Why would it depend on the library? how many orders would someone doing high frequency trading require? The last basket trader I messed with only wanted half a million orders for the entire day. But looking at the GPU spec I could probably parse half a million FIX messages per second, but would anyone want that?

Comment: @mfc - Did you even understand what I said ? Don't be a hot head and shake off that *holier than thou* attitude. Why wouldn't it depend on the library, aren't you using a FIX library(engine) to send/receive your FIX messages ?

Comment: @mfc that's between you and the business, not something that the Internet can answer for you.  Some traders might want to process half a million messages per second, and others wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXAntenna - the engine that I use - is advertised at 60k-115k messages/sec per instance.

It really depends entirely on your needs. If you are doing it for experimentation, then my answer is "as fast as possible, and even then, that's not fast enough".

If you are interfacing to the Namibian Stock Exchange, then a reasonable amount is 1000/day - there were 250 trades on the NSX last year.

I'm going to go the spectacularly unexciting route and say 1/sec.